# How to use hyper link in EditorTemplate in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc 3. I have to display a CheckBoxList and get the checked values from the CheckBoxList. For this I am using EditorTemplate. I have to show the Name of the checkbox as a hyper link. The following is my code.

Parent View:

```
if (Model.MyObject.PresentedDocuments != null && Model.MyObject.PresentedDocuments.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyObject.PresentedDocuments)
    </div>
}
```

EditorTemplate View:

```
@model Transaction.DocumentDto

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DocumentId)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Type)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
```

Essentially I want to have `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)` to be surrounded by an anchor link whose href value is available in Transaction.DocumentDto. If I could do a foreach loop I could do the following:

```
foreach (var docs in Model.Documents)
{
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedGroups" value="@docs.DocumentId" id="@docs.DocumentId"/>
        <label for="@docs.DocumentId">
            <a href="@docs.Url">@docs.Name</a>
        </label>
    </div>
}
```

Unfortunately I have to use only EditorTemplate.

Comment: `<a href="@Model.Url">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)</a>`

Comment: Thanks! That resolved it!!

Comment: As part of the same question, how could I arrange the resulting checkboxes into a 3 column rows. Currently they are displayed horizontally